Short session duration in Rails 7 PWA
My Rails 7 PWA is logging me out:

Any time I force close the PWA, and
After just a few hours even if the PWA is left running in the background

This only happens in the installed PWA on a mobile device. I can run the app in a desktop browser and remain logged in for days.
The PWA is simple right now and works as expected: I can install it on a device, the service worker registers, and the manifest is read fine.
I'm using Devise and ActiveRecordStore for authentication and session storage. My devise.rb config is the default.
Rails.application.config.session_store :active_record_store, key: 'app_session', expires_after: 1.month

I've verified the session table exists and Devise is creating sessions in that table when I authenticate.

Switched to ActiveRecordStore for sessions and verified it stores sessions in the DB.
I added expires_after: 1.month to the ActiveRecordStore configuration with no effect.
Tried different values for config.timeout_in = 14.days in devise.rb with no effect.


PWAs on mobile devices might handle background processes and session data differently than desktop browsers.
Mobile operating systems often have aggressive memory and resource management strategies, which can impact session persistence.
Check the mobile browser settings or the own mobile OS setting like battery optimization.

I took a look but I also have other PWAs installed on the same device and they don't have logout issues. I can force close most of them and still be logged in when the app restarts.
